# Running different macros based on cell value in excel 2003 doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I am running excel 2003 and trying to call a couple of different macros, based on the cell value (all in the current worksheet). My macro doesn't work and I am having trouble to understand why - here is the macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C9")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("C9")
            Case "Select":  HideST
            Case "YES":     HideST
            Case "NO":      FindST
        End Select
     End If
 End Sub
```

I've also tried this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C9")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case ActiveSheet.Range("C9")
            Case "Select": HideST
            Case "YES":    HideST
            Case "NO":     FindST
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

But, it did not work either ...
Then I tried completely different macro - with the same results:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Range("C9")
    If Target.Value = "YES" Then
        Call HideST
    End If
    If Target.Value = "NO" Then
        Call FindST
    End If
End Sub
```

When I select different value on C9 - nothing happens as macro is not triggered. Can anybody help please?

Cheers
Mile`S

Comment: In the VBA editor place a Break-point in front of the Sub and step through each line of code using F8 to see if it gets triggered (it will).Then look carefully at Target.Value (add a Watch to see its value). Most likely you will see that VBA tries to compare "yes" = "YES", or "Yes" = "YES". This can be fixed like this: `If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then`

Comment: Thanks Paul, I did what you suggested - If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then
 Call HideSTand it did not work ... I am using excel 2003

Comment: Were you able to step through the code? ("didn't work" is not specific enough - what exactly is the issue?)

Comment: Macro just doesn't get triggered, nothing happened .. I did notice when I try to close worksheet, before it close I get the msge about Compile Error: "Ambiguous Name detected:Worksheet_Change" and this line gets highlighted: "Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" ??

Comment: That means that your VBA module contains 2 Subs called "Worksheet_Change" please remove one of them

Comment: Thank you! I did it, but macro still doesn't get triggered on on the cell selection as explained above ... I am having trouble to understand how to 'step through each line of code' as you asked me to ?! :(

Comment: Sure: First place a Break-point in front of the Sub - click the gray border to the left of the line `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` (you should see a round dot on the border). Now the code will stop on that line when you change the value of cell C9, then step to the next line in the code by pressing F8 on the keyboard

Comment: Thanks Paul, I have done it .. .when placing a round dot on the border, the whole line gets highlighted in red ... I can not see where the code stop when I change value on C9 .. nothing is indicating that ... also nothing happens when I press F8 ?!

Comment: It looks like the code doesn't get triggered on the Change event. How do you change the values in cell C9? (from dropdown list, or manually entering the word "yes" or "no"?)

Comment: From drop down list (created by Data Validation: Select, YES,NO)

Comment: Most likely you placed the code in the wrong VBA module - I'll provide an answer with an image so you'll understand easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** (like Paul suggested in his comment)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C9")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Ucase(Range("C9").value2)
            Case "SELECT", "YES":  HideST
            Case "NO":             FindST
        End Select
     End If
 End Sub
```

**Option 2**

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C9")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("C9").value2
        Case "Select", "YES" : HideST
        Case "NO":             FindST
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

For Option Compare have a look at the documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-compare-statement)

Comment: Paul, none of these options works for me  :(   Once again could it be Excel 2003 version problem?

Comment: @Miles - Don't focus on the version of Excel (these should work, but there are other issues to be fixed first). Let's make sure that VBA is triggered as expected

Comment: @Miles: You have to put the code of either Option 1 or Option 2 into the worksheet module. Run a Debug/Compile. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hi Storax, Thank you for trying to help, I really appreciate it ... I did debaging .. a part of the code: "Option Explicit" goes above macro code break like and sits under End Sub of the previous macro ... WHen I debag I've got the msge : Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function or End Property"   I try to run the code without 'Option Explicit' but no results as macro was not triggered ...

Comment: @Miles: The Option statements have to be on the top of the module, the first line. And then you should put the different subs into the module.

Comment: I know, but it goes automatically above the break line and sits under the End Sub of previous macro and I can not keep it in the right place ? ! Excel 2003 version problem ??

Comment: That sounds strange. You should be able to copy & paste the code like in Paul's screenshot below. Maybe you just delete everything in the worksheet module and then paste the code into the module.

Comment: Yeah ...I've tried in a new module ... the first macro on a clean sheet .. and the "Option Explicit" get separated from the macro by the line .. so it sits on top of macro separated  ?! Very strange ....

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target

        If .Column = 3 And .Row = 9 Then

            Select Case UCase(.Value2)

                Case "SELECT", "YES":   HideST
                Case "NO":              FindST

            End Select

        End If
    End With
 End Sub
```

---

Make sure you place the code in the module for the proper sheet (where cell C9 is)

[image: VBE sample]

Comment: Yes!!!! That was the key! It works now when assigned to the proper Sheet. All other macros just work fine from Module 1, but this one had to be assigned to the proper Sheet - and I noticed you have specified properly a column and a raw as well as using capitals in my selection. Thank you very much Paul for your great help and you Storax too. Great guys!

Comment: I'm glad it helped !